# std::stringstream and getline slow down towards end of file

Tags: c++, getline, stringstream, c++98

**Note: C++98**

I have a while loop that reads a file with approx 60,000 lines and parses a series of values into a stringstream. While running, for some reason as it approaches 40,000 it begins to slow down.

I found that by making the `std::stringstream ss` variable static, it speeds up the read substantially, however the values never change, and I think it's becuase `std::stringstream` is constantly declared.

I tried moving it out of the while loop, however the `std::getline` in the `while` complains on compile.

I'm still a little new to C++, so sorry if the solution is straight forward.

```
void readTable(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str());
    std::string line_str;
    int countA = 0;

    while (std::getline(file, line_str)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line_str);
    // read and parse ss >> variables
    
    countA++;
    cout << countA << endl;
    
    usleep(1);
    }
    file.close();
}
```

I plotted the data rate in matlab, and as you can see up to about line 40,000 it's pretty linear, however after that the rate slows down.

[image: Matlab plot of file read]

Comment: `I plotted the data rate`  How do you measure the data rate? What exactly did you plotted? How big is the file (in bytes)? Please create an [MCVE]. @edit `I implemented a count with timestamp` How did you implemented it? Please show all the relevant code. (this is important, most commonly the method of measuring may be flawed)

Comment: I implemented a count with timestamp at the end of the while loop that I let run which output to a file, then oused that data to plot inside MATLAB.

Comment: And what if the code for the timestamp and file output is responsible for the slowdown?

Comment: `// read and parse ss >> variables` The slowdown could well be in this part. Try to comment that code out, then you'll time the actual file reading.

Comment: Probably because of cache.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but if you find out that the creation of a `stringstream` instead is indeed a bottleneck, then you can create the stream outside the loop and use `stringstream::str()` to set its content in each iteration (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/)